# npgsql driver sslmode missing verify-ca and verify-full -- PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

As per links below, PostgreSql supports several **ssl mode connections**, but its ADO.net driver, **npgsql does not support the modes verify-ca and verify-full**, which are supported by the its JDBC driver.

Is there any reason for this?
Is it possible to use these modes somehow else?

*PostgreSql docu*
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/libpq-ssl.html

*Npgsql driver docu*
https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html

*JDBC driver  docu*
https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ssl-client.html

Answer (score 7):

Npgsql will by default verify the server certificate, so `SSL Mode=Require` would correspond to libpq's `verify-ca` or `verify-full` (the documentation is not entirely clear on that).

From the documentation link in your question:

> By default, Npgsql will validate your server's certificate; if you're using a self-signed certificate, this will fail. You can instruct Npgsql to ignore this by specifying `Trust Server Certificate=true` in the connection string. To precisely control how the server's certificate is validated, you can register `UserCertificateValidationCallback` on `NpgsqlConnection` (this works just like on .NET's [`SslStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream)).